# R crashes when STM model converge

Tags: r, rstudio, topic-modeling

Relatively frequently R crashes when STM model converge. See image below for one example after a 30h+ estimation session. This has happened on two different computers, with different data sizes. I have not been able to identify any specific patterns leading to these crashes—as the crashes do not seem to be deterministic.

The model estimation settings is

```
# full
Year <- year(df$date) # year data from the environment

stmFit.full <- stm(out$documents, out$vocab, K = 0, prevalence =~ s(Year) , 
                  max.em.its = 150, init.type = "Spectral", seed = 300, verbose = T)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Additional information:
a)

```
> #systeminfo
> > library(stm) stm v1.2.2 (2017-03-28) successfully loaded. See ?stm for help.
> > sessionInfo() R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build
> 9200)
> 
> Matrix products: default
> 
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252 
> LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
> LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    
> 
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
> 
> other attached packages: [1] stm_1.2.2
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.4.1   
> Matrix_1.2-10     tools_3.4.1       Rcpp_0.12.12      grid_3.4.1      
> data.table_1.10.4 lattice_0.20-35  
> >
```

b)
I have also filed a report on the development site in github: https://github.com/bstewart/stm/issues/89

c)
Image of the crash:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this issue. See Github at : https://github.com/bstewart/stm/issues/89